# Why is this findOne in a template event causing a call stack size error?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I am trying to have a `forEach` in SpaceBars that shows some buttons that can be pressed for each thing in an array. However, when I press the button, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded underscore.js:1025
>    _.(anonymous function) @   underscore.js:1025
>    EJSON.clone    @   ejson.js:475
>    (anonymous function)   @   ejson.js:494
>    *.each.*.forEach   @   underscore.js:113
>    EJSON.clone    @   ejson.js:493
>
> ... same stuff for a while ...
>
> *.each.*.forEach   @   underscore.js:113
>    EJSON.clone    @   ejson.js:493
>    (anonymous function)   @   ejson.js:494
>    *.each.*.forEach   @   underscore.js:113
>    EJSON.clone    @   ejson.js:493

This is the `findOne` that's causing the error:

```
"click .acceptFriend": function(requester){
  currentUserId = Meteor.userId(); 
  requesterUsername = requester;
  requesterId = friendRequests.findOne({$and:[{target:currentUserId}, {requester:requesterUsername}]})._id;

  Meteor.call("acceptRequest", requesterId, requester);
}
```

I know it's the `friendRequests.findOne` because I have done console logs on each line, and that is the line that breaks it. I have tried several different variations, but it seems that any type of find on the `friendRequests` collection in that context breaks it. The relevant part of the template is this:

```
{{#each getRequests}}
    {{requester}} <button class='acceptFriend'>accept</button>
{{/each}}
```

Why is this error happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at [the documentation about events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps):

> The handler function receives two arguments: `event`, an object with
>   information about the event, and `template`, a template instance for the
>   template where the handler is defined. The handler also receives some
>   additional context data in `this`, depending on the context of the
>   current element handling the event. In a template, an element's
>   context is the data context where that element occurs, which is set by
>   block helpers such as `#with` and `#each`.

**To sum up:** events in Meteor do *not* receive their data context as an argument: they receive the *event* object and the *template instance* where the event occured. The data context is stored in `this`.

So what you should probably do is the following:

```
"click .acceptFriend": function(event, template){
  currentUserId = Meteor.userId(); 
  requesterUsername = this.requester;
  requesterId = friendRequests.findOne({$and:[{target:currentUserId}, {requester:requesterUsername}]})._id;

  Meteor.call("acceptRequest", requesterId, requesterUsername);
}
```